# SQL list items bought by everyone

Tags: sql, oracle, items

Any thoughts on how to write this in SQL?

> List all the customers who bought products bought by every other

The schema is:

- `Customer` (cId, cName)
- `Buys` (tId, cId, pId)
- `Product` (pId, pName)

I have been trying to select all the distinct items and group the table Buys using that but without luck.

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: And db schema would be helpful...

Comment: I have tried to intersect the items but without luck

Comment: Customer(cId, cName)
Buys(tId, cId, pId)
Product(pId, pName)

Comment: edit the question, adding the DB schema and what you tried so far

Comment: That looks like a homework assignment

Comment: @Dellein - Do any of the 3 answers posted so far work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- Customers who bought products bought by every other customer
SELECT DISTINCT cId,cName
  FROM Customer c1
      ,Buys b1
 WHERE c1.cId = b1.cId
   AND pId IN
-- Products bought by every other customer   
(SELECT pId
   FROM (SELECT pId,COUNT(1) count_p
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
                       cId,pId
                  FROM Buys)
          GROUP BY pId) t1
       ,(SELECT COUNT(1) count_c
           FROM Customer) t2
  WHERE t1.count_p = t2.count_c)
```

Try the above query and see if it works. I didn't get a chance to test this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, tested on random data, works well. May be slow on large amount of data..

```
SELECT cid, NAME
  FROM (SELECT c.cid, c.name, cc.cnt, COUNT(b.pid) cpid
          FROM customer c, buys b, product p, (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM customer) cc
         WHERE c.cid = b.cid
           AND b.pid = p.pid
         GROUP BY c.cid, c.name, cc.cnt)
 WHERE cpid = cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a list of customers who have **only** bought products bought by **every customer**. So I think you should flag all products as being SoldToAll or not in a sub query. Then you have to decide if your customer bought at least one of the products flagged as SoldToAll = 1 and none of the products flagged as SoldToAll = 0.

```
-- Step 1. Flag products as SoldToAll
SELECT 
    pid
    ,CASE COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SoldToAll
FROM 
    (SELECT cid,pid 
    FROM buys 
    GROUP BY cid,pid
    ) CustProd
GROUP BY
    pid
-- Step 2. Use the above to get list
;WITH Prod AS 
    (SELECT 
        pid
        ,CASE COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SoldToAll
    FROM 
        (SELECT cid,pid 
        FROM buys 
        GROUP BY cid,pid
        ) CustProd
    GROUP BY
        pid)
SELECT
    DISTINCT Buys.cid
FROM
    Buys
WHERE
    pid IN (SELECT pid FROM Prod WHERE SoldToAll = 1)
EXCEPT
SELECT
    DISTINCT Buys.cid
FROM
    Buys
WHERE
    pid IN (SELECT pid FROM Prod WHERE SoldToAll = 0)
```